# How to send email notification in vTiger?

Tags: vtiger

I use vTiger for managing leads. When a new lead is assigned , I'd like to send auto email to the man whom the lead is assigned to.
When any field in a given lead record is changed, I'd like to send him and to the record's owner another email notification.
I couldn't find how to apply it.
If you know, please share the info.

Thanks in advnance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflows in vtiger can definitely accomplish what you're trying to do. If you want to try playing around in the workflows area without doing it on your own CRM just go to http://www.vtiger.com/ and create a free trial account. Or go to the demo area and try to play with workflows there.

To get to the workflows, in "Settings" toward the bottom of the page in the "Other Settings" area there should be an item titled "Workflows". In the workflows you can automate numerous business processes based on the specific conditions that you outline.

For sending an email when the record is changed, under "When to run the workflow" select "Every time a record is modified", and then click "Save" to take it to the area where you define what action you want it to perform and set it to email to the "assign to" person's email address

Using a similar methodology emails can be automated for when a lead is assigned, too. It's useful to familiarize yourself with workflows because it can automate lots of repetitive tasks and standardize numerous business processes.

Answer (score 0):

workflows in Vtiger 6.0 (or 6.1) cannot send e-mail.

I used DEMO version as well. I got same result:

Vtiger cannot send email over workflow.

---

I added two different task on same condition. (In order to understand if workflow works or not)

1) I gave an task to update one of field on somewhere. 
2) I gave an task to send an e-mail to my personal e-mail adress. (I didn't select and pre-values from vtiger. - in order to prevent any mistake).

workflow can change field that I set BUT cannot send e-mail.

Please don't ask, if mail server works or not. It works. I tried it by sending e-mails over it. All settnigsa re correct.

As a result:

Workflow - Sending e-mail - part has a bug.   (Especially I am working on SALES ORDER department)